# Magento 2 referrer URL not working and also product not adding to cart

Tags: product, url, magento2.2.4

https://hofindia.com/hof/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9ob2ZpbmRpYS5jb20vaG9mLw%2C%2C/    This Url Not working and

https://hofindia.com/hof/customer/account/login/ It's Working

Also, Product not adding in cart sometimes because of this issue.

Kindly Do Needful. I am Stuck

Comment: Sometimes referer SignIn URL working and sometimes not.

Comment: can anyone help?